# When to use "fell short"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the use & correct meaning of fell short in English, I confused where should I use it.
I have used it in one context

> You tried well but **fell short** showing your proper requirement.

is it correct? or what other situations I can use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression is "to fall short of doing something".

> You tried your best but fell short of achieving your goal.

I don't know what you mean by "showing your proper requirement".